# Adding an Item in a list with a button

Tags: 2013, list

I came across a SharePoint site that has an interesting feature.

[image]

It works exactly like "New Item" but with the added benefit of not having to go to any list to add the Item.

how can I implement this?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the same lines as Taran, you can paste the following code into a Script Editor Web Part. Be sure to link to your NewForm.aspx.

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Button Text Goes Here" onclick="window.location.href='http://yoursite/yourlist/NewForm.aspx'" />
</form>
```

Also keep in mind that if you change your default NewForm, this will need to be updated, as well.

Comment: can you tell me how I can make the NewForm page to be a pop up? so that the user doesn't' get redirected to the list after submiting

Comment: You will have to use JavaScript `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` for opening forms in pop up, check this link https://alinimer.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/open-pages-and-forms-in-modal-dialog-for-sharepoint-2013/  AND http://blogbaris.blogspot.in/2012/09/open-sharepoint-2010-display-edit-new.html

Comment: Another option would be to add `?Source=http://InsertRedirectURLHere` to the end of your NewForm.aspx url. Then when they submit or cancel on the form, it redirects to a page of your choosing.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add on to Kaylee's answer and user22005's comment. To open the new item form in a pop up, we can use the following code snippet:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Button Text Goes Here" onclick= "javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('http://yoursite/yourlist/NewForm.aspx;);return false;"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Specify which version of SharePoint you are using. I'll go the hard way and assume "Office 365".
You can achieve this with the help of Client Side Object Model of SharePoint. You can create the HTML in CEWP and the fire events through ECMA scripts or SPServices to perform various actions.

for e.g. SpServices code to add a new item:

```
$().SPServices({    operation: "UpdateListItems",   listName:    "TestList",    batchCmd: "New",    valuepairs: [["Title","TestItOut"]],
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {         console.log( "hopefully    worked" );   } });
```

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013 On-Premise

Comment: I guess i went to a more extreme solution for a very simple requirement. I simply misunderstood. J